# Dockerfile for postfix

Tags: postfix, docker

I have tried to implement postfix in dockerfile, and it failed when i tried to send a mail saying (address resolved failure). Do i need to reconfigure the docker network or just the postfix main configuration?

Sending Email:

```
sendmail to@email.com
From: from@email.com
Subject: theSubject
This is the message
.
```

Output error:

```
postfix/error[573]: 322CC760259: to=<NEXTRCPT NOT UPDATED>, orig_to=<email@gmail.com>, relay=none, delay=15, delays=15/0/0/0.1, dsn=4.3.0, status=deferred (address resolver failure)
```

postfix main configuration (main.cf)

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = meron
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, meron, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587 
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

# Enable SASL authentication
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
# Disallow methods that allow anonymous authentication
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
# Location of sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/sasl_passd
# Enable STARTTLS encryption
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
# Location of CA certificates
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libsasl2-modules postfix && apt-get -y install rsyslog; \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*;

CMD touch /dev/xconsole && chgrp syslog /dev/xconsole && chmod 664 /dev/xconsole

# RUN service rsyslog restart

RUN echo "[smtp.gmail.com]:587 email@gmail.com:password" > /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

RUN postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

RUN sed -i '/relayhost*/c\relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587' /etc/postfix/main.cf

RUN sed -i '/smtp_sasl_auth_enable*/c\smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes' /etc/postfix/main.cf

RUN sed -i '/smtp_sasl_security_options*/c\smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous' /etc/postfix/main.cf

RUN sed -i '/smtp_sasl_password_maps*/c\smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd' /etc/postfix/main.cf

RUN sed -i '/smtp_tls_security_level*/c\smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt' /etc/postfix/main.cf

RUN sed -i '/smtp_tls_CAfile*/c\smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt' /etc/postfix/main.cf

# CMD /etc/init.d/postfix restart && tail -f /var/log/syslog

EXPOSE 25

# CMD service rsyslog start && service postfix start && tail -f /var/log/mail.log
CMD touch /dev/xconsole && chgrp syslog /dev/xconsole && chmod 664 /dev/xconsole && service rsyslog start && service postfix start && tail -f /var/log/mail.log
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you configure your docker container?

Comment: Oops, forgot to add dockerfile there, hold on!

Comment: *" status=deferred  (address resolver failure)"*  - that is a DNS error. Can the container reach the resolver ip-addresses and are the populated correctly ?

Comment: @HBruijn, I have checked whether it reaches DNS servers (N.B. 8.8.8.8) and connectivity is fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can bring the container our of the docker bridge network and instead use the host's network by adding `--network="host"` as an option to `docker run .....` instead of mapping ports with the `-p` argument.

For docker-compose you can add `network_mode: "host"` instead of `ports:` & `networks:` for that specific service.

As an example when I run PHP containers on my local/dev environments.

**Docker CLI**

`docker run --rm --network="host" -v $(pwd):/app MyVendor/phpfpm71 my_command`

**Docker Compose:**

```
phpfpm71:
image: MyVendor/phpfpm71
volumes:
    - ./app:/app
network_mode: "host"
```

Answer (score -1):

I have added the Gateway Ip address to the mydestination configuration in main.cf.

Worked fine. ;)

Comment: Hi, I've added an answer that should make it so that you don't need to add the Gateway IP for docker bridge, by bringing the networking outside of the docker bridge and instead using the host network.